# How to split string using regex without consuming the splitter part?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split

How would I split a string without consuming the splitter part?
Something like this but instead `:` I'm using `#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}` regex.

```
String from = "one:two:three";
String[] to  = ["one",":","two",":","three"];
```

I already tried using commons lib since it has `StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens()` but it does not work with regex.

EDIT: I guess I should have been more specific, but this is more of what I was looking for.

```
String string = "Some text here #58a337test #a5fadbtest #123456test as well.
 #58a337Word#a5fadbwith#123456more hex codes.";

String[] parts = string.split("#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}");
/*Output: ["Some text here ","#58a337","test ","#a5fadb","test ","#123456","test as well. ",
"#58a337","Word","#a5fadb","with","#123456","more hex codes."]*/
```

EDIT 2: Solution!

```
final String string = "Some text here #58a337test #a5fadbtest #123456test as
 well. #58a337Word#a5fadbwith#123456more hex codes.";

String[] parts = string.split("(?=#.{6})|(?<=#.{6})");
for(String s: parts) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
Some text here 
#58a337
test 
#a5fadb
test 
#123456
test as well. 
#58a337
Word
#a5fadb
with
#123456
more hex codes.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `\\b` (word-break, `\` escaped) to split in your case,

```java
final String string = "one:two:three";
    
String[] parts = string.split("\\b");
for(String s: parts) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BEoIwDEXX9BSZrspCDgDjEVyxVBcFKhZL22kDjsNw9loFkWx@Jnn/Jx0f@aFrHiHYoVKyhlpx7@HEpSYTSdahR45RRiMb6OOKleikbs9X4K71KUyEwFrJTWquYAGi8StHoEaLHJ8mx7sTghZ/fouy3KGP6OLJvFUSGb1cKpoW@3zj2C89X0yfB2ADkvLlUfSZGTCzkUOlmU93F@etJbGfQ3gD)

Comment: That does work for `:` but i need it for this regex `#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}`. I edited the post to be more accurate now.

Comment: @Lynx - then go with Tim using `(?=#.{6})|(?<=#.{6})` as splitter.

Answer (score 4):

The answer given by @vrintle +1 is probably the tightest code which can be written for your exact input.  But, assuming you might have other non word characters in the input besides `:`, then you could also split more precisely using lookarounds:

```java
String from = "one:two:three";
String[] parts = from.split("(?<=:)|(?=:)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[one, :, two, :, three]
```

Comment: oh my this is beautiful!

Comment: @Eugene Stop that!  You're making me blush `:-)`

Comment: I edited the post since it wasn't exactly accurate on what I needed. And @vrintle commented what I needed exactly. But thanks anyway. :)